# Create newline before line matching a pattern, if there is no newline yet

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a text file with a few lines in it. What i am trying to do is to find all lines matching a pattern and if there is no newline (= non empty line) before them, create it. 
Something like this, but it is not working properly:

`sed -i '/[a-zA-Z0-9]/{N;/PATTERN/{s/PATTERN/\nPATTERN/}}' FILENAME`

I know it could be probably done more easily and nicely in awk or perl/bash, but i would prefer an one line/one step solution.

Sample input file:

```
LINE1
LINE2
PATTERN
LINE3

PATTERN
LINE4
```

Expected output:

```
LINE1
LINE2

PATTERN
LINE3

PATTERN
LINE4
```

Comment: Posting sample input file and expected output will get you more help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very good at sed but here's how I'd do it in awk:

```
awk 'prev != "" && /PATTERN/ { print "" } { prev = $0; print }' file
```

If `prev` (the previous line) is not empty and the current line matches `/PATTERN/` then print a blank line. Unconditionally save the current line for comparison with the next, and `print` the current line.

To achieve an "in-place" edit (like `sed -i`), just redirect the command to a temporary file and then overwrite the original:

```
awk 'prev != "" && /PATTERN/ { print "" } { prev = $0; print }' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Note that since `prev` is initially unset, this *won't* print a newline at the start of the output, even if the first line matches `/PATTERN/`. To get around this, you can change the condition to:

```
(NR == 1 || prev != "") && /PATTERN/
```

You can also achieve the in-place edit with GNU awk, using the `-i inplace` option.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [`GNU sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) (note that `awk` is a better tool for the job):

```
sed -i '/PATTERN/{x;/^$/!i\

x};h' input
```

- `h` is a command that saves the contents of the pattern space into the hold buffer. It saves the line at the end of each cycle so that it can be used as the "previous" line in the next cycle
- `x` exchanges the contents of the hold and pattern spaces. Whenever the current line matches your `/PATTERN/`, the previously saved line is put into the pattern space. If the previous line is **NOT** empty (`/^$/!`), newline is inserted with the `i` command. The current line is then put back into the pattern space with the `x` command
- If you want to add a newline even if the **first** line matches `/PATTERN/`, use:

  ```
  sed -i '/PATTERN/{1h;x;/^$/! ...
  ```

---

Further reading:

- [`GNU sed`: Less Frequently-Used Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands)
- [grymoire.com `sed` tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)